# Gollum-like wiki based on Mercurial

Tags: git, mercurial, wiki

Is there a Gollum-like Wiki (Gollum uses a Git repo to store its pages) based on Mercurial (instead of Git)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at [Hatta](http://hatta-wiki.org/). That is a Mercurial-driven wiki where you can edit the pages online and thus create new revisions in the underlying repository.

Answer (score 0):

[MoinMoin 2.0](http://moinmo.in/MoinMoin2.0) will also support hg as storage backend.

It's still some ways off, though:

> "Maybe end of 2011" is maybe not totally unrealistic.

Comment: They've replace the "2011" with "2012" :D

Comment: @AaronDigulla: it's the end of 2013, do you know what the status of this is? I wasn't able to find anything definite. Thanks.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: "As moin2 is still in heavy development, we can't give any release date yet."

Comment: @AaronDigulla: thanks for the effort of responding, though :)